# Como enviar email a una lista de correos q obtengo desde mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

Este es mi problema: estoy haciendo un servicio de notificacion automatico por email a cada unos de los clientes, el problema es que debo seleccionar los datos a eviar que corresponda a cada cliente desde la db y enviarselo a su email ya registrado, este me funciona pero envia el mismo dato que en este caso es el ultimo registro de la DB a todos los destinatario: MI PREGUNTA: Como hago para que seleccionar y q se envie el dato correspondiente de cada cliente?

```php
 
***texto destacado*** 
//configuración base de datos y phpmailer

$hoy = date('Y-m-d'); //fecha actual
$conn = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $password, $baseDatos, $port);

 
$mail->setFrom('non-reply@gmail.com', 'mi-nombre');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_email, serv_type, cost, fecha_del_serv FROM mi_tabla 
WHERE dia_a_notificar = ? LIMIT 100");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $hoy);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

$emails = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($emails, $row["Email"]);
    $mail->Body = htmlentities("COURTESY REMINDER FOR YOUR PAYMENT ", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "<br>";
    $mail->Body .= htmlentities("Tipo de servicio: " . $row["serv_type"] . "<br>", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail->Body .= htmlentities("Costo del servicio: " . $row["cost"] . "<br>", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $mail->Body .= htmlentities("Servicio realizado: " . $row["fecha_del_serv "] . "<br>", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  }
}
try { foreach ($emails as $email) {
        $mail->addAddress($email);
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = 'Notice';
        $mail->send();
        echo "Notice Sended";
    }
    $emailList = implode("','", $emails);
    echo $emailList;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error al enviar el correo electrónico: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Hola, podrias dejar mas informacion sobre la pregunta como adjuntar codigo para que la comunidad pueda ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: lo estaba haciendo pero no se como, ya que me daba un error y no supe como subirlo

Comment: Hola, podrias darle un vistazo a esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Por Favor alguien q me ayude con ese problemilla lo necesito ASAP(lo mas pronto posible) 

Comment: Intenta partir en pequeños bloques el problema: 1. ¿Puedes mostrar una lista de todos los correos a ser enviados? 2. ¿Puedes mostrar en una vista el formato: "correo+cuerpo del mensaje"? Saludos.

Comment: No llamas a la columna del correo por su nombre correcto, debería ser: `$row['client_email']`.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas usando la libreria `phpmailer` te comento que es muy posible que se vea como spam el enviar correo masivos pero hay dos formas de hacer, enviarlo de forma individual o enviarlo en un solo grupo de correo, los dos metodo requiere de que iteres con un bucle a los usuarios.

***Ejemplo 1:*** un correo para cada usuario.

```
$result = .... //LISTA DE CORREOS

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    ...
    $mail->addAddress($row['email']);
    ...
    $mail->send();

}
```

***Ejemplo 2:*** Meter a todo el mundo en un solo correo.

```
$result = .... //LISTA DE CORREOS
$mail = new PHPMailer;
...
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mail->addAddress($row['email']);
}
...
$mail->send();
```

Las mismas tecnicas las puedes usar para adjuntar multiples archivos, enviar CC o CCO a multiples usuarios, etc.

Una breve explicacion, piensa siempre primero en que quieres hacer o que comportamiento quieres que tenga tu sistema, si tienes que hacer dibujos una hoja de papel o en powerpoint es mucho mejor hacerlo para tener una idea clara de que cosas debe hacer lo que planeas programar.

Cuando hagas lo anterior comprenderas o estaras en el nivel de los diagramas de flujos que no es nada mas que un bosquejo para cumplir los objetivos y tener claro cuando y donde debe ir un bucle, un inicio, una toma de decicion, un final...

Comment: Mil gracias, lo solucione con un bucle:
foreach ($result as $row) {
    try {
        $mail->addAddress(htmlspecialchars($row['Email']), htmlspecialchars($row['cliente']));

pero ahora lo q sucede es q al 2do recipiente le llegan dos emails: uno con el contenido del 1ro y el segundo con el conteneido q le corresponde. Aun no he podido solucionar! ya q x logica deberia ser asi pero no es el objetivo.